# WCF open amount of threads on start

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

Currently implementing a sample project with WCF hosted on a windows console application.

From what I understand, the WCF calls will be managed by a system threadpool. The number of threads will grow to match the number of concurrent requests.

I would like to know if it is possible in my WCF service to set the number of open threads so that it is always the same from start to finish. That way I wouldn't have to wait for threads to open.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: _" I wouldn't have to wait for threads to open"_ - the thread pool reuses threads..

Comment: *"From what I understand, the WCF calls will be managed by a system threadpool. The number of threads will grow to match the number of concurrent requests."* This is almost certainly not true and will only vaguely correct if you have long-lived ***synchronous*** (i.e. blocking) methods in your WCF handlers. Without knowing what you are doing and how you are doing it, any answer will be guesswork.

Comment: @stuartd Yeah, but don't these threads have to be opened at first? Say for example at some point the throughput of my WCF doubles, won't there be a bunch of new threads opened and added to the pool, possibly slowing down the processing? My understanding is very minimal, sorry if that is not how it works at all.

Comment: @spender Sorry if the question is vague, the work I'm doing is basically just to try and understand what is possible with WCF, so it is quite vague for me too but I'm still trying to ask a precise enough question that can be answered. Can you precise what you mean by this is not true? Won't there be threads added to the threadpool to match the throughput of my WCF service?

Comment: @lhbortho That would depend on whether or not your services are CPU constrained or IO constrained, and in the case of IO, whether or not you use synchronous or asynchronous methods to do your IO.

Comment: @spender Some services will be IO constrained, and use synchronous methods for those IO. Is there a way to setup the base amount of IO threads? That way no new ones would be created following a service call?